# Comparative functions in defined OWL classes

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

Let's suppose a simple ontology with the following classes/subclasses:

- Subject

  - Subject_under_60
  - Subject_over_60

I have a set of incoming data which is transformed into a set of Subject individuals having a data property "has_age".

I'm looking for some nice workaround how to define the Subject's subclasses in the way that reasoners would be able to classify the subject individuals. So far, I was thinking about two approaches:

1. Data pre-processing where I would add a flag if the subject is or is not over 60 (e.g. subject01 dataProperty:isOver60 True).
2. Data post-processing, i.e. solve it later in the process in SPARQL queries.

But what I would really appreciate is something like

Subject_over_60 isEquivalent Subject AND (has_age ***valueOver*** "60"^^xsd:int).

My goal is to simplify the pre-processing as much as possible (in best case leave there just a date of birt) and leave most of the classification work up to reasoners. Since specific value comparison is limited to "exact value" only, I'm aware that it won't be so easy. I would appreciate any idea or your best practice to solve a similar problem.

Comment: Hm, `has_age some xsd:int[>= 60]`?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I had no idea that something like that is possible nor find that in documentations. It works perfectly, thank you very much @StanislavKralin!